# calculate the percentage increase or decrease in a list of values in java

Tags: java, algorithm

i'm trying to build an data structures and algorithms program using java.
and i wanna ask if anyone know
How do i calculate the percentage increase or decrease in a array.
i try this code--but apparently its not the correct way

```
public class test{
    static float checkMov(int arr[], int n) {
            float var1, var2, result = 0;
    
            var1 = arr[0];
            var2 = arr[1];
    
            // Calculate successive change of 1st 2 change
            result = var1 + var2 + ((var1 * var2) / 100);
    
            // Calculate successive change
            // for rest of the value
            for (int i = 2; i < n; i++) {
                result = result + arr[i] + ((result * arr[i]) / 100);
            }
    
            return result;
        }
}
```

```
import static test.testt.checkMov;

public class tester {

    public static void main(String[] args) 

        int[] arr = {1931534,1933628,1935714,1925709,1923754,1923578,1923049,1928556,1928289,1924857};


        int N = arr.length;

        // Calling function
        float result = checkMov(arr, N);

        System.out.println("Percentage change is = " + result + " %");

    }
}
```

Run->
Percentage change is = **Infinity** %

Comment: What does `var1 + var2 + ((var1 * var2) / 100)` signifies?

Comment: `float` is probably too small for these kind of calculations, with the numbers you're dealing with. I'd use `double` or `Double`.

Comment: Tried any debugging yet? What were your insights?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you're dealing with the numbers, which could go in the larger values. Datatype `float` has limited range to handle the numbers between `3.40282347 x 10e38 and 1.40239846 x 10e-45`. So change the method return type of `checkMov` to double. Also handle the values in `double`, which ranges between `1.7976931348623157 x 10e308 and 4.9406564584124654 x 10e-324`.

```
static double checkMov(int arr[], int n) {
        double var1, var2, result = 0;

        var1 = arr[0];
        var2 = arr[1];

        // Calculate successive change of 1st 2 change
        result = var1 + var2 + ((var1 * var2) / 100);

        // Calculate successive change
        // for rest of the value
        for (int i = 2; i < n; i++) {
            result = result + arr[i] + ((result * arr[i]) / 100);
        }

        return result; // This returns 7.0955315970304415E44 
    }
```

Comment: ,it works very well ,thanks for your help <ARIGATO^_^>